# Dynamically want to get images from other fragments

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

So basically in this the user can dynamically add the images and the images gets uploaded in firebase too. Also in this there are 2 fragments so in MySnapFragment the user can add the images and can also see the images. But all the Uploaded images should be also seen in aMySnapFragment too when the specified button is clicked .How can I achieve that??Any help is highly appreciable. So basically i want the updated images to be shown when button in amySnapFragment is clicked.

this is my aMySnapFragmen.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".aMySnapFragment"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient">
    
        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="341dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="38dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="544dp"
            android:text="   CALLIGRAPHY DOODLE SNAPS"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/user_btn"
            android:layout_width="338dp"
            android:layout_height="88dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="184dp"
            android:background="@color/LightBlue"
            android:text="SHOW ALL CALLIGRAPHY SNAPS"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="25dp" />
    
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

this is my MySnapFragment.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MySnapFragment"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient">
    
        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="341dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="38dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="544dp"
            android:text="   CALLIGRAPHY DOODLE SNAPS"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    
    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="245dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="267dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_photo_alternate_24" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/upload_btn"
            android:layout_width="304dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="142dp"
            android:background="@color/LightBlue"
            android:text="UPLOAD"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/showall_btn"
            android:layout_width="304dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="53dp"
            android:background="@color/purple_200"
            android:text="SHOW ALL"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginEnd="153dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="211dp" />
    
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

this is my MyAdapter.java file

```
    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    
        private ArrayList<Model> mList;
        private Context context;
    
        public MyAdapter(Context context , ArrayList<Model> mList){
    
            this.context = context;
            this.mList = mList;
        }
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item , parent ,false);
            return new MyViewHolder(v);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Glide.with(context).load(mList.get(position).getImageUrl()).into(holder.imageView);
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mList.size();
        }
    
        public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    
            ImageView imageView;
            public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
    
                imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.m_image);
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my ShowActivity.java file

```
    public class ShowActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private ArrayList<Model> list;
    
        private MyAdapter adapter;
    
        private DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Image");
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_show);
    
            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            list = new ArrayList<>();
            adapter = new MyAdapter(this , list);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    
            root.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                        Model model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Model.class);
                        list.add(model);
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    
                }
            });
        }
    }
    
this is my item.xml code    
    
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:elevation="10dp">
    
    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/m_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />
    
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```